# Getting data from different Database connection to a List c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I'm using 2 data contexts.

Here is my current application, I want to get some data from `database01` and join the data with `database02`make a list, and return a view.

This is my current code.

```
private zSqlLink dbs = new zSqlLink();
private zSqlData db = new zSqlData();
// GET: Selfcare

public ActionResult PendingSelfTasks() 
{
  IEnumerable <SelfCareTasks> pendingTasks = new List <SelfCareTasks> ();

  var list = (from l in dbs.SelfCareTasks where l.Is_Service_Accepted == false 
              && l.Status == true select new {
              l.Id, 
              l.Service_Id, 
              l.Customer_Id, 
              l.Service_End_Date, 
              l.Service_Price
              }
              ).ToList();

  pendingTasks = (from d in list
                  join c in db.Customer on d.Customer_Id equals c.Id 
                  join ser in db.Services on d.Service_Id equals ser.Id 
                  select new SelfCareTasks {
                   Id = d.Id,
                   CustomerName = c.Sur_Name + " " + c.Name,
                   ServiceName = ser.Service_NameEng,
                   ServicePrice = d.Service_Price,
                   EndDate = d.Service_End_Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

                 }).ToList();

  return View(pendingTasks);
}
```

The first `var list` shows there are 2 data in the list.

But when It is joined with the `PendingTasks` list, the result becomes null.

Any other solutions for this matter ?

Comment: Simple way is to check customer id from list variable using contains and then use the filtered data.

Comment: So your inner join doesn't return any data, it means no matching records found. Are you sure you have matching records in database as per your logic? If so you can use left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways:

```
Bring the results from both tables into memory and use LINQ to Objects to join them. (Only recommended for a small number of records because of memory/processor overhead)
Add one of the tables to the other data context (Copy the DBML over and prefix the name attribute with the name of the database, e.g. database2.dbo.MyTable) (it seem this is added later, because I remembered he suggested to create a view here)
```

Another way is

```
 3. Create a View at the database that get the data from the two tables in the two database.
```